# Does it make a difference where I put this if statement?

Tags: c++, pointers, if-statement, linked-list

So I was working on a lab with link lists and I got to a part where I have to output an error message if an element wasn't found after traversing the list. My question is, shouldn't it make a difference whether I put this if statement after the while loop or after the else statement? If I put it after the second else, shouldn't the function end as soon as that else finishes executing? 
I tried running it and I still got the same expected output, but I'm trying to figure out where it makes the most sense to put it since labs are graded on efficiency and style.

```
void AnyList::deleteNode(int deleteData)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        cerr << "Cannot delete from an empty list.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        Node *current = ptrToFirst; 
        bool found = false; 

        if (current->getData() == deleteData)
        {
            ptrToFirst = current->getPtrToNext();
            delete current;
            current = NULL;
            count--; 
            found = true; 
        }
        else
        {

            Node *trailCurrent = current;
            current = current->getPtrToNext(); 

            while (current != NULL && !found)
            {
                if (current->getData() == deleteData)
                {
                    trailCurrent->setPtrToNext(current->getPtrToNext());
                    delete current;
                    current = NULL;
                    trailCurrent = NULL;
                    count--;
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    trailCurrent = current; 
                    current = current->getPtrToNext();
                }
            }
            //if (!found)             <-- Does it make more sense to put it here?
            //{
            //  cerr << "Item to be deleted is not in the list.\n";
            //}

        }
        //if (!found)                 <-- Or here?
        //{
        //  cerr << "Item to be deleted is not in the list.\n";
        //}
    }

}
```

Comment: Where it would make a difference is if `bool found = false;` were declared within the scope of the `else {` (along with `Node *trailCurrent = current;`). In that case, the first `if` is the only one where `found` would still be in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the `if (!found)` block into the more limited scope where it might actually run helps the reader understand and maintain the code.

There's no *functional* difference (i.e. the program does the same thing either way).

There shouldn't be a *performance* difference (with an optimised build).  When `current->getData() == deleteData` is `true` it will have set `found` `true`, so there'll be no point checking for `if (!found)`.  Your compiler *should* be clever enough to jump from the end of the statement block controlled by `if (current->getData() == deleteData)` past the `if (!found) { ... }` block, in which case the performance will be identical to having had the `if (!found) is the more localised scope.